# ListDensityPlot - Ticks on axis

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, ticks

I have a table of data of dimensions 150x51, each of the 150 points (frequency of a wave) corresponds to to 51 angles. I want to make a `ListDensityPlot`, and while the command on its own gives me the plot I want, I cannot understand how to change the value points of the axes.

`DataRange` kind does the job, but I want it to show more names of points. `Ticks` doesn't seem to work on `ListDensityPlot` . This is my command:

```
 ListDensityPlot[1 - RLfrl, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}], DataRange -> {{0, Pi/2}, {0, 10^6}}, FrameLabel -> {"Angle of incidence [rad]", "Wave frequency  \[Omega] [\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(6\)]\) \1/s]"}]
```

and this is the picture I get:

[image]

Basically I want to refine the x-axis to show more points, and while we're at it, how can I tell him to show me the angles in rad, I.e instead of 1.57 to write `π/2` ?

Comment: you need `FrameTicks` ( not `Ticks`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FindDivisions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindDivisions.html) to find ticks that are integer multiples of `Pi/2`:

> - FindDivisions[{$x_{min}$, $x_{max}$}, $n$] 
>     finds a list of about $n$ "nice" numbers that divide the interval around $x_{min}$ to $x_{max}$ into equally spaced parts.
> - FindDivisions[{$x_{min}$, $x_{max}$, $dx$}, $n$] 
>     makes the parts always have lengths that are integer multiples of $dx$.

Example:

```
data = Table[Sin[x] Cos[ y/200], {y, 0, 1000, 1}, {x, 0, 4 Pi, 4 Pi/ 50}];
ListDensityPlot[data, DataRange -> {{0, 4 Pi}, {0, 1000}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {FindDivisions[{0, 4 Pi, Pi/2}, 10], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Compare with `Range`:

```
FindDivisions[{0, 2 Pi, Pi/4}, 7]
```

> {0, π/2, π, (3 π)/2, 2 π}

```
Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/4]
```

> {0, π/4, π/2, (3 π)/4, π, (5 π)/4, (3 π)/2, (7 π)/4, 2 π}